# Lumen - Whoops, looks like something went wrong

Tags: laravel, lumen

How can I print the error message on browser where I access my app instead of seeing 'Whoops, looks like something went wrong.' which is not very helpful and is very annoying when I have to go to the storage/logs/lumen.log to find the error?

I am using Laravel's Lumen and it is not as friendly as Slim. Any ideas how can I see the error on screen instead?

Comment: Set APP_DEBUG to true in the configuration

Comment: where is this configuration? lumen does not comes with a configuration file.

Comment: you gotta copy .env.example to .env

Comment: You need to set it up. You can either use PHPDotEnv or create a configuration file. [Lumen Configuration](http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/installation#configuration)

Comment: @RDelorier in addition to your comment for your configuration values to be loaded, OP will need to uncomment the `Dotenv::load()` method call in your bootstrap/app.php file.

Comment: where is `.env.example`? the lumen site is poorly documented for someone who is completely new to laravel !

Comment: It's described in the link i sent you above under "Environment Configuration" and .env.example is just in the root of your project. It ships with Lumen.

Comment: found it. but it is already set APP_DEBUG to true. and if I uncomment the Dotenv::load(), i get an error `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Dotenv: Environment file .env not found or not readable. ...`

Comment: got it work, at last! it is really an unfriendly framework!!